# How to change image source based on state in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qml, bind

I use qt quick 2.0. A gridview is bound to a c++ model as described in [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html). In the gridview's delegate, I use an image to show an icon. I try to use state property to change image source and bind state to the model.

The expected result would be on release the selected screen image should be changed to running icon.

The actual result it image doesn't change. If I use setName instead of setState in ScreenManager::setScreenState, it shows changed screen name correctly.

Is there any better solution?

Screen.h

```
class Screen
{
public:
    Screen(QString name, int gridId, bool active = false);

    QString name() const;
    int gridId() const;
    bool active() const;
    QString state() const;

    void setName(QString n);
    void setActive(bool a);
    void setState(QString s);

private:
    QString m_name;
    int m_gridId;
    bool m_active;
    QString m_state;
};
```

ScreenManager.h

```
class ScreenManager : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    enum ScreenRoles {
        NameRole = Qt::UserRole + 1,
        GridIDRole,
        ActiveRole,
        StateRole
    };

    ScreenManager();

    void addScreen(const Screen& screen);
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex& index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
    QModelIndex getIndex(int row, int column = 0,
        const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;

    Q_INVOKABLE int getScreenGridId(int index);
    Q_INVOKABLE bool getScreenActive(int index);
    Q_INVOKABLE void swapScreens(int index1, int index2);
    Q_INVOKABLE void setScreenState(int index, QString s);
    Q_INVOKABLE QString getScreenState(int index);
protected:
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const;

private:
    QList<Screen> m_screens;
};
```

ScreenManager.cpp

```
#include "ScreenManager.h"

#include "Screen.h"

ScreenManager::ScreenManager()
{
    int index = 0;
    for (;index < 15; index++) {
        addScreen(Screen(QString ("Screen%1").arg(index), index, false));
    }
    m_screens[2].setActive(true);
    m_screens[6].setActive(true);
    m_screens[7].setActive(true);
    m_screens[8].setActive(true);
    m_screens[12].setActive(true);
}

void ScreenManager::addScreen(const Screen& screen)
{
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
    m_screens.append(screen);
    endInsertRows();
}

int ScreenManager::rowCount(const QModelIndex& parent) const {
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    return m_screens.count();
}

QVariant ScreenManager::data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const
{
    if (index.row() < 0 || index.row() >= m_screens.count())
        return QVariant();

    const Screen& screen = m_screens[index.row()];
    if (role == NameRole)
        return screen.name();
    else if (role == GridIDRole)
        return screen.gridId();
    else if (role == ActiveRole)
        return screen.active();
    else if (role == StateRole)
        return screen.state();
    return QVariant();
}

QModelIndex ScreenManager::getIndex(int row, int column,
                             const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return hasIndex(row, column, parent) ?
                createIndex(row, column, (void*)&m_screens[row])
                : QModelIndex();
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> ScreenManager::roleNames() const
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[NameRole] = "name";
    roles[GridIDRole] = "gridId";
    roles[ActiveRole] = "active";
    roles[StateRole] = "state";
    return roles;
}

int ScreenManager::getScreenGridId(int index)
{
    return  m_screens.at(index).gridId();
}

bool ScreenManager::getScreenActive(int index)
{
    return  m_screens.at(index).active();
}

void ScreenManager::swapScreens(int index1, int index2)
{
    int min = index1 < index2 ? index1 : index2;
    int max = index1 > index2 ? index1 : index2;
    m_screens.swap(index1, index2);
    beginMoveRows(QModelIndex(), max, max, QModelIndex(), min);
    endMoveRows();

    if (max - min > 1) {
        beginMoveRows(QModelIndex(), min + 1, min + 1, QModelIndex(), max + 1);
        endMoveRows();
    }
}


void ScreenManager::setScreenState(int index, QString s)
{
    // if use setName, the grid view can show the changed screen name 
    m_screens[index].setState(s);
    dataChanged(getIndex(0), getIndex(rowCount() - 1));
}

 QString ScreenManager::getScreenState(int index)
 {
     return m_screens[index].state();
 }
```

QML

```
GridView {
id: gridView
x: 82
y: 113
width: cellWidth * 5
height: cellHeight * 3
clip: true
anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
anchors.bottomMargin: 70
anchors.topMargin: 100
anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
anchors.top: parent.top
flickableDirection: Flickable.HorizontalAndVerticalFlick
cellWidth: 90; cellHeight: 90;
property bool ignoreMovementAnimation: true

MouseArea {
    id: gridViewMouseArea
    hoverEnabled: true
    preventStealing : true
    property int currentGridId: -1
    property int preIndex
    property int index: gridView.indexAt(mouseX, mouseY)
    anchors.fill: parent
    onPressAndHold: {
        currentGridId = screenManager.getScreenGridId(index)
        preIndex = index
        gridView.ignoreMovementAnimation = false
    }
    onReleased: {
        currentGridId = -1
        screenManager.setScreenState(index, "running");
    }
    onPositionChanged: {
        if (currentGridId != -1 && index != -1 && index != preIndex) {
            if (screenManager.getScreenActive(index)) {
                screenManager.swapScreens(preIndex, index)
                preIndex = index
            }
        }
    }
}

model: screenManager
delegate: Component {
    Item {
        id: gridViewDelegate
        width: gridView.cellWidth; height: gridView.cellHeight
        state: state

        states: [
            State {
                name: "running"
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: itemImage
                    source: "qrc:/res/image/screen_icon_running.png"
                }
            },
            State {
                name: "idle"
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: itemImage
                    source: "qrc:/res/image/screen_icon_idle.png"
                }
            }
        ]

        Image {
            id: itemImage
            parent: gridView
            x: gridViewDelegate.x + 5
            y: gridViewDelegate.y + 5
            width: gridViewDelegate.width - 10
            height: gridViewDelegate.height - 10;
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
            smooth: true
            source: "qrc:/res/image/screen_icon.png"
            visible: active

            Text {
                text: name
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            }

            Rectangle {
                anchors.fill: parent;
                border.color: "grey"
                border.width: 6
                color: "transparent"; radius: 5
                visible: itemImage.state === "active"
            }

            // specify the movement's animation for non-active screen icons
            Behavior on x {
                enabled: !gridView.ignoreMovementAnimation && itemImage.state !== "active"
                NumberAnimation { duration: 400; easing.type: Easing.OutBack }
            }
            Behavior on y {
                enabled: !gridView.ignoreMovementAnimation && itemImage.state !== "active"
                NumberAnimation { duration: 400; easing.type: Easing.OutBack }
            }

            // specify the shaking animation for non-active screen icons when hold one icon
            SequentialAnimation on rotation {
                NumberAnimation { to:  2; duration: 60 }
                NumberAnimation { to: -2; duration: 120 }
                NumberAnimation { to:  0; duration: 60 }
                running: gridViewMouseArea.currentGridId != -1 && itemImage.state !== "active"
                loops: Animation.Infinite
                alwaysRunToEnd: true
            }

            // specify the active screen's new position and size
            states: State {
                name: "active"
                when: gridViewMouseArea.currentGridId == gridId
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: itemImage
                    x: gridViewMouseArea.mouseX - width/2
                    y: gridViewMouseArea.mouseY - height/2
                    scale: 0.5
                    z: 10
                }
            }

            // specify the scale speed for the active screen icon
            transitions: Transition {
                NumberAnimation { property: "scale"; duration: 200}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: And `Screen.cpp`, `main.cpp`? I can't compile it as it is. Also, it's quite a lot of code. You should try to simplify it to something smaller that still reproduces the issue.

Comment: Also, we don't have any of your images, so consider changing them to rectangles or find images online that you can point to instead.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have tried to minimized the code. The image doesn't really relate to the issue, so you can simply use placeholder. Screen.cpp is mainly setter and getter. No point to put in those tedious code. main is the one typically generated by Qt 5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a naming problem, because state is also know for the state property in your item delegate.

After i changed:

```
roles[StateRole] = "statetest";
```

in you c++

and:

```
state: statetest
```

in your qml,
it works.

Or simply:

```
state: model.state
```

in your qml

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by binding image source to another property in Screen, stateIamge, rather than binding it to state directly.

But I'm still interested to see why binding to state doesn't work.